Inverse Kinematics solver parameters
I've been using the Drake InverseKinematics solver. Sometimes it's unable to solve for desired pose even though a solution exists. (I know that the solution exists because if I manually find the joint positions necessary to hit my desired pose.) I'm wondering if it's possible to tune any of the parameters inside the IK solver, i.e., the step size, number of iterations, number of resets (i.e., if it's doing something like gradient descent, allowing it to randomly restart somewhere else).
Also, I believe that the drake InverseKinematics solver doesn't allow for self collision. Is there any way I can turn this off? I am doing collision checking on my own elsewhere. Even if my desired pose is unachievable due to self collision, I still want to know what the joint angles are that would reach that position. It would help with debugging.
Here's my code for reference:
def solve_with_initial_guess(
        self,
        goal_pose: RigidTransform,
        initial_guess: NodeLike,
        ik_frame: str = "gripper_frame",
    ) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64] | None:
        self.ik = PydrakeInverseKinematics(self.plant, self.plant_context)  # type: ignore  # noqa: PGH003
        self.ee_frame = self.plant.GetFrameByName(ik_frame)

        self.p_WG_lower = goal_pose.translation() - np.repeat(self.position_tolerance, 3)
        self.p_WG_higher = goal_pose.translation() + np.repeat(self.position_tolerance, 3)

        q0_node = initial_guess
        q0 = np.array(q0_node)

        self.ik.AddPositionConstraint(
            self.ee_frame,
            np.zeros(3),
            self.plant.world_frame(),
            self.p_WG_lower,
            self.p_WG_higher,
        )

        self.ik.AddOrientationConstraint(
            self.ee_frame,
            RotationMatrix(),
            self.plant.world_frame(),
            goal_pose.rotation(),
            self.orientation_tolerance,
        )

        self.ik.AddMinimumDistanceLowerBoundConstraint(0.001, 0.01)

        prog = self.ik.get_mutable_prog()
        q = self.ik.q()
        prog.AddQuadraticErrorCost(np.identity(len(q)), q0, q)
        prog.SetInitialGuess(q, q0)

        result = Solve(self.ik.prog())

        if result is None:
            return None

        q_sol = result.get_x_val()
        if result:
            times = [0, 2]  # 2 seconds trajectory
            next_sol = q_sol.copy()
            next_sol[0] += 1.0
            key_frames: list[np.ndarray] = [q0, q_sol]

            self.plant.SetPositions(self.plant_context, q_sol)
            current_link_pose = self.plant.CalcRelativeTransform(
                self.plant_context,
                self.plant.world_frame(),
                self.plant.GetFrameByName(ik_frame),
            )

            # Find collisions in the current_link_pose

            # Check if the arrays are close enough
            are_close = np.allclose(
                current_link_pose.translation(),
                goal_pose.translation(),
                atol=0.005,
                rtol=1e-4,
            )

            are_close_rot = np.allclose(
                current_link_pose.rotation().ToQuaternion().wxyz(),
                goal_pose.rotation().ToQuaternion().wxyz(),
                atol=1e-2,
                rtol=1e-2,
            )

            if not are_close:
                logger.debug("Solver failed to reach goal pose")
                logger.debug(f"Solver translation: {current_link_pose.translation()}")
                logger.debug(f"Goal translation: {goal_pose.translation()}")
                logger.debug(f"Solver q_sol: {q_sol}")
                return None

            if not are_close_rot:
                logger.debug("Solver failed to reach goal rotation")
                logger.debug(f"Solver rotation: {rotation_to_string(current_link_pose.rotation())}")
                logger.debug(f"Goal rotation: {rotation_to_string(goal_pose.rotation())}")
                return None

            if len(key_frames) != len(times):
                msg = "Mismatch in solution size and times"
                raise ValueError(msg)

            return key_frames[1]

        return None



I'm wondering if it's possible to tune any of the parameters inside the IK solver, i.e., the step size, number of iterations, number of resets (i.e., if it's doing something like gradient descent, allowing it to randomly restart somewhere else).

When you call Solve(ik.prog()), you could pass in the initial guess and solver options as
solver_options = solvers.SolverOptions()
solver_options.SetOption(solvers.SnoptSolver.id(), OPTION_NAME, OPTION_VALUE)
Solve(ik.prog(), q_initial, solver_options)

Depending on which solver you use (SNOPT/IPOPT), you can set the options. For a complete list of the solver options, please refer to their manual https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/guides/sndoc7.pdf. We also have a tutorial on this, please check drake.mit.edu -> Resources -> tutorials -> "Setting solver parameters".
